# Placeholder looks weird in Chrome, How to Solve

Tags: html, css

As per below Image In Chrome browser, Placeholder not works well... It is slideing to left side.

How i can solve this.

**I didn't use any CSS for Placeholder**

Code is just like

`<input type="text" name="users_address" placeholder="Address" required="">`

[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Comment: Please provide padding or text-indent to input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chrome only:

`::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-indent:15px;}`

Comment: without webkit-input-placeholder its working fine in my chrome

Comment: what for old version Chrome? @Kondal  Is it working for all version?

Answer (score 3):

don't know why it's happen, you can just add this code in your css

```
input::placeholder,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input::-moz-placeholder,
input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-indent:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing issue in default feature then why not use JS solution which will work accors all browser? I have used this [plugin](http://matoilic.github.io/jquery.placeholder/) and it work in most of the browser.